# glfwLoadTexture2D not loading texture, displaying yellow filled quads instead

Tags: opengl, textures, glfw

I'm trying to load a texture using glfwLoadTexture2D to load some tga files into my program
but instead of the textures appearing on the quads they become yellow filled

I pass in

```
char path[] = "\Textures\coblestone.tga";
```

to

```
texture = loadTexture(path);
```

inside render and

this is how I load the texture

```
GLuint loadTexture(char *imagepath){

GLuint Texture;
glGenTextures(1,&Texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,Texture);

if(glfwLoadTexture2D(imagepath, GLFW_BUILD_MIPMAPS_BIT)){
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
  return Texture;
}

else
     printf("texture did not load: %d\n",errorCheck());
}
```

Thanks for the tip on the glGetError it really helped narrow down the cause. But can you tell me if you see anything wrong with the way I try to grab the image? The folder Textures is inside my project dir and I made sure everything was spelled correctly.

Comment: Have you tried using GL_QUADS? Have you enabled texturing using glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)?

Comment: So I figured out that my load texture is not working properly

I'll edit the post to show you what I mean

Comment: Actually, I just found out about the library Soil which makes texture-mapping look pretty easy. I'm going to try it.

Comment: From what I know the address is supposed to be "\\Textures\\coblestone.tga" with double backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you're initializing glfw first.

Also, I believe your path should read "Textures/coblestone.tga"

note as well 'cobblestone' has two b's not sure if your spelling is consistent.